# Independence of events that depend on one another event

Tags: probability, mathematical-statistics

$\newcommand{\P}{\mathbb{P}}$Suppose $A$ and $B$ are dependent, $C$ and $B$ are dependent, i.e.
$$ \P(A \cap B) = \P(A) \P(B|A) $$ with $\P(B|A) \neq \P(B)$ and $$\P(C\cap B) = \P(C)\P(B|C)$$ with $\P(B|C) \neq \P(B)$.

Can we say anything certain about the (in)dependence of $A$ and $C$?

If not, when are $A$ and $B$ (in)dependent?

Comment: dependance is $P(B|A) \neq P(B)$, not $P(B|A) \neq 1$.

Comment: I am not quite certain this is what you are asking, but statistical independence (hence also statistical dependence) is not transitive: see for example: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/581649/is-statistical-dependence-transitive, or http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1735078/how-to-prove-independence-is-not-a-transitive-relation, http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/215638/transitive-and-probability, etc.

Comment: @StéphaneLaurent It has been a while, so I edited the question to reflect marginals rather than "conditional certainties". (I do not think your answer depended on this, so OK?)

Answer (score 2):

Of course $A$ and $C$ are dependent in general. But they possibly are independent. Take for example two independent Bernoulli random variables $\epsilon_1$ and $\epsilon_2$ on $\{0,1\}$. Define the events $A=\{\epsilon_1=0\}$, $B=\{\epsilon_1+\epsilon_2=2\}$ and $C=\{\epsilon_2=0\}$. Then $A$ and $C$ are independent, while $A$ and $B$ as well as $B$ and $C$ are dependent.

I don't think there is a relevant characterization of the dependence between $A$ and $C$ in the general situation.